# Haskell replace a given existing book with a new book

Tags: haskell

using Haskell I am looking for a way to replace a given existing book with a new book. The new book should have a name, pages, rating and it should show how many times it was lent each week with 3 figures. The order of the books should be the same after it has been replaced.

```
data Book = Book { name:: String
                   , pages:: Int, rating:: Float
                   , timesLentEveryWeek:: [Float]
              } deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)

testData1 :: [Book]
testData1 =  [Book "Harry Potter"                    374    9.7   [7, 5, 8],
              Book "Percy Jackson & the Olympians"   530    9.8   [3 , 4, 2],
              Book "Star Wars"                       435    9.5   [9 , 7, 10]]
```

For example, if i replace **Book "Harry Potter" 374 9.7 [7, 5, 8]** with **Book "Don Quixote" 304 8.9 [4, 6, 3]** I should get the result:

```
Book "Don Quixote"                     304    8.9   [4, 6, 3],
Book "Percy Jackson & the Olympians"   530    9.8   [3 , 4, 2],
Book "Star Wars"                       435    9.5   [9 , 7, 10]]
```

I have attempted to solve the problem by adding a removeBook recursive function and adding a book by implementing @Jason Whittle 's idea to use the `map` function to add elements from one list to another. However, i am not experienced with using this function and i seem to have an issue implementing it:

```
removeBook :: String -> [Book] -> [Book]
removeBook n (p:ps)
    | n == name p = removeBook n ps
    | otherwise = p : removeBook n ps


replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> String -> [Book]
replaceBook old new booksData oldBookName = map new removeBook oldBookName booksData
```

Comment: Duplicate of removed question https://stackoverflow.com/q/61370888/67579 Same comment: what is not working with your attemt?

Comment: I think you need to derive an `Eq` instance for your `Object` type to start with.

Comment: The main problem I see straight away is that you are using a type `Book` that doesn't exist (at least in the code we see). The type you have defined is called `Object`, `Book` is its single constructor.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I have added "deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)" to the object. I am not sure how i should proceed in order to replace the book information in the mentioned example.

Comment: You might find the [break function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) useful.

Comment: I don't see an attempt here. Are we supposed to do your work for you?

Comment: Honestly, some kind of guidance would be nice. Have a nice day.

Comment: @jpmarinier Thank you. I will look it up.

Comment: Consult your study materials. Make an attempt. We can go from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’re trying to figure out how to create a function like `replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]`, where the first argument is the `Book` that you want to replace, the second argument is the `Book` you want to replace it with, and the third argument is the list of `Book`s in which you want the replacement to happen.

So let’s start with a declaration:

```
replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]
replaceBook old new bs = _
```

One design question you need to ask yourself is: what should happen if the `Book` to be replaced occurs more than once? For our purposes, we’ll answer by better defining `replaceBook`:

```
-- |Replaces all instances of the first argument with the second 
-- argument in the third argument. 
replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]
replaceBook old new bs = _
```

Another way of describing this function is that we are conditionally mapping elements of one list to another. However, at this point, our Haskell senses are tingling, because our function has basically the same type as the `map` function:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So let’s start there:

```
-- |Replaces all instances of the first argument with the second 
-- argument in the third argument. 
replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]
replaceBook old new bs = map _ bs
```

That missing argument to `map` has type `Book -> Book`. A conditional mapping can also be described as a mapping using a conditional:

```
-- |Replaces all instances of the first argument with the second 
-- argument in the third argument. 
replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]
replaceBook old new bs = map f bs
  where f a = if a == old then new else a
```

However, since this is Haskell, we’re not quite done—there’s no reason this function needs to be restricted to `Book`s!

```
-- |Replaces all instances of the first argument with the second 
-- argument in the third argument. 
replaceBook :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replaceBook old new bs = map f bs
  where f a = if a == old then new else a
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your way to solve the problem!  I have tried your solution and it works! I tried to implement the "map" function to my solution, but couldn't get it to work - I have edited the posted question with an example of what i have tried to do to solve it.

Comment: Hi, @ГаленаКолева, it seems like maybe you’re new to StackOverflow. If so, welcome! StackOverflow is intended for a question-and-answer format, not conversations. If the solution I suggested works, you might consider up-voting it, or even accepting it as the answer to your question. If you have new questions after trying it, I recommend that you post a new question for it, rather than appending it to an existing question. In this way, you are likely to have better luck with StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I can't up-vote unfortunately as I am new to StackOverflow, but I have accepted it as an answer. I will post a new question as I am looking for a more specific solution now.