# Haskell replacing data in a list with new data

Tags: haskell

I have been trying to replace a given existing book with a new book in a list. The new book should have a name, pages, rating and it should show how many times it was lent each week with 3 figures. The order of the books should be the same after it has been replaced.

```
data Book = Book { name:: String
                   , pages:: Int, rating:: Float
                   , timesLentEveryWeek:: [Float]
              } deriving (Eq,Ord,Show,Read)

testData1 :: [Book]
testData1 =  [Book "Harry Potter"                    374    9.7   [7, 5, 8],
              Book "Percy Jackson & the Olympians"   530    9.8   [3 , 4, 2],
              Book "Star Wars"                       435    9.5   [9 , 7, 10]]
```

For example, if i replace **Book "Harry Potter" 374 9.7 [7, 5, 8]** with **Book "Don Quixote" 304 8.9 [4, 6, 3]** I should get the result:

```
Book "Don Quixote"                     304    8.9   [4, 6, 3],
Book "Percy Jackson & the Olympians"   530    9.8   [3 , 4, 2],
Book "Star Wars"                       435    9.5   [9 , 7, 10]]
```

I have attempted to solve the problem by adding a removeBook recursive function and adding a book by using the `map` function to add elements from one list to another. However, i am not experienced with using this function and i seem to have an issue implementing it:

```
removeBook :: String -> [Book] -> [Book]
removeBook n (p:ps)
    | n == name p = removeBook n ps
    | otherwise = p : removeBook n ps


replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> String -> [Book]
replaceBook old new booksData oldBookName = map new removeBook oldBookName booksData
```

Comment: If you want to remove or add a book, `map` can’t help you: a property of `map` is that it cannot change the number of elements in a list. However, there is another way to implement this using `map`: just `map` through the list of all the books, checking whether each book is equal to your old book, and if it is, replacing it with the new book. Like: `map (\b -> if b == oldBook then newBook else b) bookList`. Does this help at all?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This answers my question.

Comment: I’ll post that as an answer then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell replace a given existing book with a new book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373165/haskell-replace-a-given-existing-book-with-a-new-book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove or add a book, `map` can’t help you: a property of `map` is that it cannot change the number of elements in a list. However, there is another way to implement this using `map`: just map through each element of the list of books, checking whether each book is equal to your old book, and if it is, replacing it with the new book: `map (\b -> if b == oldBook then newBook else b) bookList`. This should let you replace `oldBook` with `newBook` without changing the order of elements.

(One slight problem: if you have duplicate books, this will end up replacing both equal books, rather than just one. If this is a problem for you, you will need to use a different approach — in this situation, I’d use recursion.)

Comment: Regarding your last comment in parenthesis, It might be best to use another data structure like a Map instead of going for a very niche recursive implementation over a List.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you would like to archive. If you want to replace all occurrences of the given book the map function is ok. However, if you want to replace only the first one the better way is to use something like:

```
replaceBook :: Book -> Book -> [Book] -> [Book]
replaceBook _ _ [] = []
replaceBook old new (x:xs)
  | old == x  = new:xs
  | otherwise = x:replaceBook old new xs
```